# How to change ant-design Tabs default border color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I can't change the default border color of antd [Tabs](https://ant.design/components/tabs/).

**Tabs with Default border:**
[image: tabs-default-color]

**What I want is this:**
[image: tabs-black-border]

somehow, I was able to achieve this but it's not responsive, it takes more time.
It messed up with the mobile screen, etc.

```
...
/* rest of css in codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/so-change-antd-tabs-default-border-color-40gmb?file=/index.css */
...

  .ant-tabs-content-holder {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: grey;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
  }

 .ant-tabs-content-holder:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    height: 1.1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;

    left:  0%;
    width: 24.8%;
    background-color: white;
  }
```

This is how it looks on the Mobile screen. I think I can use many breakpoints for different screen width and change the percentage of `left` and `width` in `.ant-tabs-content-holder:after` but it's tedious.

[image: not-responsive-small-screen]

How to achieve this in a simpler way? Any idea? is there any ant design `vars` for tabs border that I can use with webpack or `less`? antd docs has style props for it? I will appreciate your help.

Check out code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-change-antd-tabs-default-border-color-40gmb?file=/index.js)

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/r1YwsR

Comment: @m4n0 I think yes, I just need to change the default border color to black

Comment: @m4n0 please post the code if you have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.ant-tabs-card > .ant-tabs-nav .ant-tabs-tab { /* For tabs border */
  border-color: black;
}

.ant-tabs-top > .ant-tabs-nav::before { /* For the line to the right and close to the tabs */
  border-color: black;
}

.ant-tabs > .ant-tabs-nav { /* So that there is no gap between the content and tabs */
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ant-tabs-content-holder {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black; /* Border for the content part */
  border-top: transparent; /* Remove the top border so that there is no overlap*/
}
```

You just need to override the above 4 classes to achieve your layout:

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://6tqnp.csb.app/)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: your solution is neat. btw would you like to explain me why  ` .ant-tabs-top > .ant-tabs-nav::before` selects only the part of border right to `top tabs` ? my css understanding is not that good :(

Comment: I get it now why you had used selector `before`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just tried overriding existing borders(with same selectors) seems does the job.

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-change-antd-tabs-default-border-color-forked-tkg3h?file=/index.css

updated antd dependency on 2022-08-24

Comment: your solution looks good to me, I'm going to check it out now

Comment: the link to csb is not working

Comment: @Ebrahim it was just antd version mismatch, just updated them. it should work now.